# Does natural light affect sneaking?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I know that artificial light (i.e. lights generated by lamps, torches, et cetear) [affects sneaking,](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37662/does-light-affect-sneaking) but I'm not sure if this applies to natural light (light generated by the sun) as well.

Does natural light affect sneaking?

Comment: Are you talking about screen brightness or how easy it is for enemies to detect you?

Comment: The latter, how easy it is for enemies to detect the player-character.

Comment: Oh, are you trying to perform some act during the day time?

Comment: I don't like the way that this question has been rephrased. While it's good to set the precedent, I don't doubt that natural light affects detection. I may get this out of the way by finding some consistent test, so that I may move on to asking my original question.

Comment: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8395/when-is-it-the-darkest-vs-is-there-darkness

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the definition of a word (which would be better on [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com).  It does not reference any in-game usage of that word or concept.

Comment: How is player-character visibility (as referring to its usage in another, great answer) not a reference to in-game usage of that word or concept? It seems that you didn't even vote to close it based on that reason.

Comment: Okay,so I've edited your question some. I tried to cut down on the the formal and scientific terms you used, as well as made it more concise. This should make it more clear what you're asking. However, I *do* think that this question is a duplicate of the "Does light affect sneaking?" question. Natural light and artificial light should both be covered by that question. I'm sorry for all the trouble you've had to go through just trying to get your original question answered, but sometimes we just mess up and edit and close questions when they shouldn't be.

Comment: @DavidM I just checked out the revision history, and I don't see how this question in both its original and current revision is asking about the definition of a word. It's asking about how a game mechanic (light or luminosity) works in TES V: Skyrim.

Comment: @galacticninja Read revision #4.  It quotes Merriam Webster, etc.  That is what I responded to at the time.  In that revision, it took 3 read-throughs to see that it had any mention of a game mechanic.

Comment: @DavidM In that revision, I think OP intended the definitions to help clarify what he meant by luminosity and the other terms he used (and was not asking about their definitions). Anyway, those have now been removed in the question's current revision, and the question is now not off-topic as explained in your comment. Did you originally vote to close as a dupe or as off-topic?

Comment: @galacticninja Off-topic.  I will now retract because of the current revision.

Comment: I don't see how this isn't a duplicate, now that it's been completely reworded.  The original one asks about light in general, of which this would be a subset.

Comment: @Frank I agree with your reasoning. If I revert it back from Wipqozn's edit, would it still be a duplicate?

Comment: No, but then it would be a dupe of your newer question.

Comment: @NiteCyper My edit is asking the same question as your one about luminosity, I just made it easier to read.

Comment: @Wipqozn No, I was asking if natural light fluctuates over time (specifically, a day). You edited it so that my question was asking whether or not natural light affects sneaking. Your question, for example, asks if there is a difference between natural and artificial (interior or torch) light. If there isn't a difference, only artificial light would affect sneaking. My original question is not relevant to artificial light.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Elder Scrolls Wiki entry on Sneak](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Sneak_(Skyrim)) (emphasis added):

> Characters' and animals' ability to notice the Dragonborn is dependent on a large number of factors, including their Sneak skill, line of sight, **the level of light on their current position**, how heavy the sneaker's armor is, whether this armor is heavy or light, enchantments on the armor (muffle), spells cast (muffle), if weapons are drawn, if magic is equipped, how fast they are moving, and the effects of any active perks.

So, the time of day may not directly effect your ability to hide, but the ambient light in your current location does, and that can be directly effected by the rising/setting sun, full moon, etc.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question as [kotekzot](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/19827/kotekzot) [rephrase](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/155456/3)d it:

I'd like to get back to my [original](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/155456/1) [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/155720/when-is-the-darkest-time-of-day) now.

Yes, I know that the evidence isn't flawless, but I am convinced, by my prior belief and this evidence, to move on unless someone has solid counter-evidence. I note, for science, that it's possible that I got lucky and fluked on [the skill checks](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/106948/46216).