# When is the darkest time of day?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

What does darkness refer to? Light in regards to player-character [visibility](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/106918/when-should-i-enchant-with-muffle-instead-of-sneak/106948#106948).
Why am I asking this? I want optimal conditions for sneaking, so I want to know what time of day I should be performing covert ops.

If you have a suggestion on how to make this question less ambiguous, please comment.

Comment: can you clarify the difference between this question and your other one? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/155456/revisions

Comment: My other one, as kotekzot commandeered it, asks the binary question of if natural light affects detection whatsoever. This question assumes that natural light affects detection and instead asks, in a sense, when is the best time to sneak outside? This question as it is phrased now can not be answered simplistically "at night".

Comment: I suggest you make a meta post about it then, if @kotekzot changed the meaning of the entire question and wrong answers gets posted you should revert and bring it to his attention (or to meta), not post the question again.

Comment: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8395/first-possibility-vs-sub-possibilities

Answer (score 1):

It depends where you are. In the East, such as Riften, it can be dark until 10:00 am, but in the far west places like Rorikstead and Helgen, dawn comes at around 4:00 am, and in the middle, like Whitrun and Dawnstar, morning comes around 8:00 am.
If you want to sneak around anywhere, though, 8:00 pm-8:00 am are usually fine.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have any hard evidence to back this, but I think that any time the sun isn't up you're in the dark. That said, you really still have to avoid light sources (fires, lanterns, etc). There's also no telling (for me anyway) if the moons cast any light. So to be safe (and roleplaying?) do your sneakiest sneaks during the new moon stages. ;)

Comment: I can say that is not true. I was playing as a vampire and it was early morning and the sun wasn't out at all (it still looked like a starry night) and all of the sudden the screen flashed and said "Your vampire blood boils in the sun."

Comment: Then it might have something to do with the actual time instead.

Answer (score -5):

i have actually figured it out,it depends on the day 9-12 would usually be the darkness but its doesn't really affect how detectable you are.

Comment: being dark absolutely affects how detectable you are...